# Possibility to trigger only child for 2 div's where one div is hidden

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have the only-child css property trigger. When there are two children for a div but one of them is hidden using css?

So I tried

```html
<div class"hide-if-one-child">
   <div>Hi, am I the only one?</div>
   <div class="hide"></div>
</div>
```

With css

```css
.hide:empty {
  display: none;
}

.hide-if-one-child:only-child {
  display: none;
}
```

So I supposed that because the second div was hidden, it might hide the top most div, as there is only one child "displayed". I suppose, that it the `display:none` does not do this though. Is there a way to do this using only css?

Comment: No you can't with `:only-child`

Comment: This could work with :has, but browser-support is not great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @niorad pointed out you could use [has pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) but be aware that the current browser support [is not that great](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

```css
.hide-if-one-child:has(div:empty) {
  border: solid 2px black; 
  /*display: none*/
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-if-one-child">
  <div>Hi, am I the only one?</div>
  <div class="hide"></div>
</div>

<div class="hide-if-one-child">
  <div>Hi, am I the only one?</div>
  <div class="hide">No you're not</div>
</div>
```